# Does Anypoint studio 5.2.3 Community Edition with runtime 3.7 CE support Munit?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Please clarify the doubt

I'm going to use 5.2.3 Anypoint studio with 3.7 CE runtime, will it support Munit?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the compatibility info. As it just mention 3.6 and 3.7, it is available for both CE and EE runtimes. CE compatibility is expected as default and would state otherwise if it was only compatible with EE: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/munit-1.0.0-release-notes#compatibility-information